# ListView with multiple EditText and different keyboard layout

Tags: android, listview, focus

I have a ListView in android with two rows, each row contains an EditText. The first EditText has inputType of type text, and the second one's type is number. So the simplified code in getview looks like this:

```
if (row2) {
    row2EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER |
        InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
} else if (row1) {
    row1EditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT |
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE);
}
```

The first EditText receives the focus just fine and I can enter my message. But when I click on the second EditText, it receives the focus for a fraction of a second and then EditText1 takes the focus back!

Now if I enter text on EditText1, dismiss the keyboard manually, and then click on EditText2, it works just fine! or if I use the same keyboard layout for both, the focus works as expected.

Any idea why changing the keyboard layout between EditText views messes with the focus?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I can't answer your question why but maybe you can work around it by clearing the focus of EditText1 when clicking on EditText2. What happens if you click on EditText2 and then on EditText1?

Comment: @m.hashemian did you find any solution for this.